# External microphone not working Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

My headset microphone is not detected on Kubuntu, yet the speaker is fine. I had the same problem on Windows 10 (dual booted) but I fixed it by downloading the audio drivers for my motherboard. They don't offer drivers for linux on the website, though. Should I be trying to download the drivers on linux?

I've tried re-installing pavucontrol, pulseaudio and alsa, which didn't work. I've noticed in pavucontrol, however, that my mic seems to have two profiles: "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP sink)" and "Headset head unit (hsp/hfp)" and when I switch to the latter the microphone is detected, but does not capture any sound.

Specs:

```
Ryzen 5600G
MSI b450m bazooka max wifi
Sillicon power 16gb 3200mhz ram
Headset: RUNOLIM Bluetooth Headphones
```

Comment: Windows drivers do not work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Bluetooth headphones do indeed have typically two profile: A2DP (HiFi audio, no microphone) and HFP (Mono + microphone). This has nothing to do with audio drivers, this is all about Bluetooth profiles.

Comment: I see. But even when I switch to do HFP profile the mic doesn't detect any sound @ChanganAuto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've fixed the problem by installing pipewire and disabling pulseaudio. [Here's the website where I found the fix](https://atish3604.medium.com/solved-bluetooth-headset-mic-not-working-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-86a5236444d0).

PS: Every time there is a — character replace it with -- for example where it says `systemctl — user daemon-reload` run `systemctl --user daemon-reload`